# Extract strings between two characters in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following string

```
- Pri."Priority Description"
```

How can extract `Pri` and `Priority Description` separetly ? in excel , I try this `=MID(A1,FIND("\",A1)+1,FIND("\",A1,4)-FIND("\",A1)-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First enter the following **UDF**

```
Public Function GrabString(s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String) As String
    Dim L2 As Long, L2x As Long, sx As String
    L2 = Len(s2)
    L2x = InStr(s1, s2) + L2
    sx = Mid(s1, L2x)
    GrabString = Left(sx, InStr(1, sx, s3) - 1)
End Function
```

This **UDF** will return a substring that is encompassed by two other strings.
Then with data in **A1,** in **B1** enter:

```
=GrabString(A1,"- ",".")
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=GrabString(A1,"""","""")
```

to display:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Text to Columns` option in `DATA` of `Excel.Select "."(Dot)` as delimiter.

It will work